# creating a 3d sphere scatter plot in mathgl using a datafile

Tags: plot, 3d, mathgl

I'm trying to create a 3d scatter plot with spheres using a data file of the format:

X  Y  Z  val \n
0  0  0  1  \n
0  0  1  0  \n
0  0  2  0  \n
0  0  3  0  \n
.
.
.

I can read the file but I can't seem to find any where how to plot a set of spheres using matrix

(my goal is to get something like [this](http://www.ornl.gov/info/ornlreview/v38_1_05/images/a06_membrane_full.jpg))

P.S.

If any of you know how to get the same plot using gnuplot or any other command line/script file tool I'll be happy.

Answer (score 0):

Just draw spheres in the cycle.

```
for(long i=0;i<n;i++)
  gr->Sphere(mglPoint(x[i],y[i],z[i]),r[i]);
```